# Python source code line normalizing formatter

Tags: python, pep8

There are many formatters which will do pep8/flake or alternative styles (e.g. black). But are there tools, which do reverse? Given a python code, convert it to have one stanza per line? No multiline arguments for function call, etc?

I need it to to make few automatic changes, and multiline arguments just break my sed (I want to replace debug/info stanza with 'pass' in a large project to see if it speedup things).

Or, may be, is there a way to configure existing fromatters to do so?

Comment: Don't use `sed` to edit source code. You probably want to use something like LibCST to parse your code into a concrete syntax tree (CST), modify the syntax tree, then serialize the CST back to Python source code. See https://libcst.readthedocs.io/en/latest/codemods.html#library-of-transforms.

Comment: (The kind of formatter you are asking for could *itself* be implemented as a codemod.)